# No output for bifurcation diagram

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, nonlinear

I am plotting a bifurcation diagram for my system with `A` on x-axis following the code in, [How to make a bifurcation diagram of the Lorenz system under a varying parameter value?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159211/how-to-make-a-bifurcation-diagram-of-the-lorenz-system-under-a-varying-parameter). But I get an empty output

```
res = Internal`Bag[];(*a place to store results*)tmax = 10;(*how long \
to run for each A value*){x0, y0} = {0, 1};(*initial ICs*)
\[Omega] = -2.5; \[Tau] = 1; Do[
sol = NDSolve[{Sqrt[-1]*x'[t] == \[Omega]*x[t] - 
   A*x[t]*Abs[x[t]]^2 - \[Tau]*y[t], 
 Sqrt[-1]*y'[t] == \[Omega]*y[t] - 
   A*y[t]*Abs[y[t]]^2 - \[Tau]*x[t], x[0] == x0, 
 y[0] == y0,(*save extrema of z[t]*)
 WhenEvent[x'[t] == 0, Internal`StuffBag[res, {A, x[t]}]]}, {x, 
 y}, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];
(*save end value for next ICs*){x0, y0} = {x[tmax], y[tmax]} /. 
sol;, {A, 200, 0, -0.1}];

ListPlot[Re@Internal`BagPart[res, All], 
PlotStyle -> {Gray, Opacity[0.1], PointSize[0.001]}]
```

The initial conditions are flexible and can be changed for atleast generating some output, I tried with `{x0,y0}={0,1}` and  `{x0,y0}={1,1}` but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of a complex function, we use `Re[x'[t]]` to select events.

```
res = Internal`Bag[];(*a place to store results*)
tmax = 10;(*how long to run for each A value*)
{x0, y0} = {0, 1};(*initial ICs*)
ω = -2.5; τ = 1;
 Do[
     sol = NDSolve[{I*x'[t] == ω*x[t] - 
           A*x[t]*Abs[x[t]]^2 - τ*y[t], 
         Sqrt[-1]*y'[t] == ω*y[t] - 
           A*y[t]*Abs[y[t]]^2 - τ*x[t], x[0] == x0, 
         y[0] == y0,(*save extrema of z[t]*)
         WhenEvent[Re[x'[t]] == 0, 
          Internal`StuffBag[res, {A, Re[x[t]]}]]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 
         tmax}][[1]];
     (*save end value for next ICs*){x0, y0} = {x[tmax], y[tmax]} /. 
       sol;, {A, 200, 0, -0.1}];
Table[ListPlot[Internal`BagPart[res, All], 
  PlotStyle -> {Gray, Opacity[0.1], PointSize[0.001]}, 
  PlotRange -> op], {op, {Automatic, All}}]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Could you add a bit of text saying what the problem was?

Comment: Secondly, could you please tell how you get the second plot? the one with thin lines on the right?

Comment: Lastly, The vertical axis corresponds to `x[t]` or `x'[t]`?

Comment: I added one line to the code that describes the construction of the figures. The figures show the real part of $x(t)$ - `Re[x[t]]`, depending on the parameter A.

Comment: @Alex thanks. So it seems that the usual bifurcation shape as in [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81107/bifurcation-diagram-for-piecewise-function?rq=1), [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13277/mathematica-code-for-bifurcation-diagram?rq=1) etc is not possible for this equation then?

Comment: I would prolly use the more conventional `Sow[]`/`Reap[]` instead of ``Internal`Bag[]`` for this, since this isn't in a compiled function anyway.

Comment: I agree. What does the code look like in this case?